# How to set data to a template in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm new to meteor i want to set data to a template

In Javascript:

```
Template.test.helpers({
  configDoc:function(){
    return Session.get('configDoc');
  }, 
});
```

In html:

```
<template name="test">
  {{#each doc in configDoc}}
    {{> details doc }}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

I want to set the data on the `details` template (not shown here) to `doc` using `{{> details doc }}` but this is not working for me :-(

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[See the docs here.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/livehtmltemplates)

Change Template.test to this:

```
<template name="test">
  {{#each configDoc}}
    {{> details}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

in `Template.details`, you can directly display any attributes in the template with`{{attrA}}`.

Or if you create helper functions the current doc can be accessed as the `this` object.